# CSS Bootstrap 3.0 field with icon

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a form with 3 fields, two of them are for entering dates. I was requested to add an icon to the very end of the field.

This is the result:
[image]

If you see the field that has the icon expands beyonds the other fields to the left and right so it looks pretty ugly.

This is the code:

```
<div class="form-horizontal">

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Begin</label>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" />

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">End</label>
        <div class="input-group col-md-8">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" />
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i></span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Text Search</label>
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <input type="text" class="form-control">

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">

            <button id="btnSavedMessages" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

> Any clue on how to do it right?

Comment: The docs tell you how to do this... http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your fixed code please copy it and paste it

```
<div class="form-horizontal">

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Begin</label>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy">

    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">End</label>
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <div class="input-group ">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i></span>
    </div></div>
</div><div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Text Search</label>
    <div class="col-md-5">
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <button id="btnSavedMessages" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button></div></div></div>
```

I have tested it works fine. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Some CSS is messing with you.
Your line with `input-group col-md-8` is apparently malfunctioning. 
I made an example:

https://plnkr.co/edit/gxpaP4wR8cZzb3E4CvtR

Check if you have some custom CSS that is overriding bootstraps'.

Answer (score 0):

Use my code this is working fine.

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="form-horizontal">

  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Begin</label>
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" />

    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">End</label>
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" />
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Text Search</label>
    <div class="col-md-5">
      <input type="text" class="form-control">

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">

      <button id="btnSavedMessages" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```